# How do I use SDl_Threads properly?

Tags: multithreading, sdl

I am new to threads,SDL and how graphic work in general. I've been looking through all of LazyFoo's SDL tutorials, and had helped me greatly. But in his tutorials about multi threading, he commented that you should never use video functions in separate threads, or might cause problem. I am curious how it should be done, as I still have a vague understanding of graphics and threads.

As one of my projects is a shoot'em up, I was wondering if I should create one thread that displays all the graphics, one threads receives all the player input for his ship, and another thread for the enemy AI.

If this is NOT how it should be done, (I think it's wrong) does anyone have any advice of how graphics should be implemented with user input and enemy AI with threads?

For the Lazyfoo's tutorials, this is the link:
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

It can be a lot easier to separate threads on a responsibilities basis when you're starting out. The more "correct" way of approaching this, which leads to greater scalability, is to use thread pools. There are pre-built thread pool solutions out there, including one for SDL.

If you're using OpenGL or DirectX to do rendering, I doubt that the calls to those APIs will generate much overhead, so you could at least do the (necessarily) sequential parts of your game loop in the main thread: get input, update world model (including using results of ai calcs), render. Then you can have AI, network threads running in parallel. Thus you don't need to worry about a separate rendering thread. There is one exception to this: if you are doing computationally heavy (and I mean as in raycasting/raytracing heavy) rendering in software, then you would be better off somehow performing rendering "logic" on a parallel thread, writing to a framebuffer, and then in your main thread doing the sequence given above, and just blitting your prepared framebuffer using eg. GDI.

In regards to rendering, yes AFAIK rendering from only a single thread (the main thread) is (or was) generally a good idea to ensure that eg. with OpenGL you have no problems. Again AFAIK this is no longer an issue on the major platforms. Also, I don't know whether GDI or DirectX separately have the same problems.

Answer (score -1):

Generally I think it is a good idea to separate the rendering thread from the UI/AI threads. It helps to keep your code more understandable. As there are many games available in source code, why don't you check out how they did it?